# Is there an adapter / Dock / hub with 2 display outputs?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

Looking around I can only seem to find an adapter / dock that only has 1 hdmi output with usb,ethernet, etc.

Are there any adapters / Docks that have 2 display outputs? So then I can plug it into the macbook pro with thunderbolt 3 and output on 2 displays. without needing to [buy 2 of these](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b&fs=f%3Dadapter%26fh%3D4595%252B45b0)

Is it not possible because of the power consumption or speeds?

Thanks!

Comment: See this answer for a possibility:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314234/dual-screen-setup-apple-cinema-displays-mac-mini/314316#314316

Answer (score 0):

A lots of Thunderbolt 3 docks exists that will allow you to have 2 display outputs. Usually these are organized such that one display is connected to an HDMI or DisplayPort output on the dock, and the other is connected to the chained Thunderbolt 3 port on the dock which is used as a DisplayPort output.

For example you could use the Elgato Thunderbolt 3 Dock, the OWC Thunderbolt 3 Dock or the Caldigit Thuderbolt Station 3.

Note: Before you rush out and buy any of these make sure that you actually have got a Thunderbolt 3 enabled MacBook Pro or similar. Your question contains conflicting information as you claim to have a MacBook with Thunderbolt 3, which doesn't exist. The MacBook (2015, 2016 and 2017) have USB-C only.

Comment: So I was looking at the newer models https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MPXT2LL/A&step=config# they say thunderbolt 3 maybe I just linked the wrong adapter, I am new to the apple world haha

Comment: That is the “MacBook Pro” - it does indeed have Thunderbolt 3, and lots of docks exists for it. You can easily connect two (or more) displays. Note that is a different product than the “MacBook” which is a much smaller computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really nice product that might interest you.

via Amazon

StarTech Thunderbolt 3 to Dual HDMI Adapter (currently @ $91.71 USA)

Shows 4K @ 60Hz & is Mac and Windows Compatible. Also can be used as USB-C.

**If you are going to use with Windows, make sure that you update your Intel Thunderbolt Controller Drivers for optimum support.

If you aren't in USA, try reaching out to StarTech directly and see if they ship to you.

Let us know if this works.

[https://www.amazon.com/Thunderbolt-Dual-HDMI-Adapter-60Hz/dp/B075CLHQY7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075CLHQY7)

Answer (score 0):

## CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock

Dual DisplayPort or HDMI versions of the [CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock](https://www.caldigit.com/mini-dock) are available.

I use the [Thunderbolt to dual DisplayPort version](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B079GXBD2V) on a recent Mac. It works well enough and is bus powered. Very rarely one of the displays will not appear on start up; unplugging the adapter or restarting fixes the problem.

Previously I tried combinations of multiple USB-C and Thunderbolt to DisplayPort adapters but nothing worked reliably.

[image: CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock]