# Connect Two Dell 27" 2719H Monitors to Macbook Air 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I'm trying to connect two Dell 27" P2719H Monitors to a Macbook Air from 2017 running Catalina 10.15.4. The Macbook Air has an Intel HD Graphics 6000 graphics card. This model also has a Thunderbolt 2.0.

Is this possible to do? So far I've successfully connected one of the monitors to the Macbook using a Dynex HDMI-->Thunderbolt adapter. I've also tried to create a daisy-chain, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the P2719H, it has DisplayPort connectivity.  Instead of converting to HDMI, you should just get a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable (mDP to DP).

You can't daisy chain and since you only have one Thunderbolt port, you will need to get either (one or the other) of:

- [Thunderbolt 2 Dock with multiple display outputs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314316/119271)
- [USB Video adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246427/119271)

However, this a lot you're asking this MacBook Air to do.  Remember, there's no discrete GPU as it's integrated into the CPU.  Video memory is taken from system memory (up to 1.5GB worth).  I wouldn't be surprised if you see a noticeable performance decrease or reduced video capability.